# Restricting number of children when using MultiValueFieldDefinition in Magnolia

Tags: content-management-system, yaml, magnolia

So I'm creating a custom dialog for a component I'm adding to a template in Magnolia CMS.

So far the following yaml is working fine.

```
form:
  tabs:
    - name: tabMain
      fields:
        - !include:/n-components/dialogs/include/backgroundColorSelectField.yaml
        - name: title
          label: Title
          class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.TextFieldDefinition
          maxLength: 75
          i18n: true
        - name: tiles
          label: Tiles
          class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.MultiValueFieldDefinition
          transformerClass: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.transformer.multi.MultiValueSubChildrenNodePropertiesTransformer
          field:
            name: compositeField
            class: info.magnolia.editor.app.field.CollapsibleCompositeFieldDefinition
            layout: vertival
            label: Collapse
            transformerClass: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.transformer.composite.DelegatingCompositeFieldTransformer
            fields:
              - name: tileTitle
                label: Tile title
                class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.TextFieldDefinition
              - name: tileText
                label: Tile text
                class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.TextFieldDefinition
                rows: 3
```

However, I would like MultiValueFieldDefinition to have a maximum (and also possibily a minimum?) number of children allowed.

Is this an option? I tried maxLength but it's not working. Docs don't talk about such a property, but maybe someone had a similar problem.

I would prefer to avoid any Java if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, OOTB:

```
 41 public class MultiValueFieldDefinition extends ConfiguredFieldDefinition {
 42
 43     private String buttonSelectAddLabel = "buttons.add";
 44     private String buttonSelectRemoveLabel = "buttons.delete";
 45     private ConfiguredFieldDefinition field;
 46
```

And `ConfiguredFieldDefinition` doesn't have any such member variable either.  In the end, the properties you may use are because some member variables exist on the underlying Java classes.

You could extend `MultiValueFieldDefinition` and add these properties, and use that in your project instead, but you said you're not interested in doing that.